# Why adding memo in recursion problem gives wrong result while removing memo gives correct answer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dynamic-programming

**Q. Write a function "canSum(target_sum, numbers)" that takes in a target_sum and an array of numbers as arguments. The function should return a boolean indicating whether or not it is possible to generate the target_sum using numbers from the array.**

- You may use an element of the array as many times as needed. You may
  assume that all numbers are non-negative.
- Eg: canSum(7, [1, 2, 5, 3, 7]) --> true
- Eg: canSum(7, [2, 4, 9, 6])    --> false

*Here is my solution,  but it only works when i remove memoization.*

```
    def canSum(target_sum, numbers, memo={}):
        if target_sum in memo:
           return memo[target_sum]
        if target_sum == 0:
            return True
        if target_sum < 0:
            return False

        for num in numbers:
           if canSum(target_sum - num, numbers, memo) == True:
               memo[target_sum] = True # removing this gives expected output.
               return True

        memo[target_sum] = False # removing this gives expected output.
        return False

   if __name__ == "__main__":
      print(canSum(7, [2, 5, 7])) # Output: True
      print(canSum(7, [2, 4])) # Output: True (while it should be false).
```

> After removing memo, now it works correctly. Please help, I cant find why is this happening.

```
for num in numbers:
    if canSum(target_sum - num, numbers, memo) == True:
        return True

return False
# Now it works fine.
```

Comment: The mutable default parameter `memo={}`  is the problem. The empty dictionary is created once, when you create the function, *not* on every call of the function. See ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument).

Comment: Because your current "memoisation" doesn't take into account _which numbers were provided_. It just returns the result for whichever list of numbers was provided the first time a given target_sum was used.

Comment: To tackle the problem with the mutable parameter you could define the function as `def canSum(target_sum, numbers, memo=None):` and in the first line `if memo is None: memo = {}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually found the answer.
In previous code `canSum(target_sum, numbers, memo={}`, `memo` was same for *all function call.*

I mean for `canSum(7, [2, 5, 7])` and `canSum(7, [2, 4])` `memo` is same for both.

So, when it calls the function for 2nd time, it checks for the previously-stored key and returns according to it.

```
  if target_sum in memo:
       return memo[target_sum]
```

And that's where, all this ghop-chop happens.

Here's my corrected code.

```
  def canSum(target_sum, numbers):
       memo = {}
       return memoCanSum(target_sum, numbers, memo)


  def memoCanSum(target_sum, numbers, memo):
      if target_sum in memo:
          return memo[target_sum]
      if target_sum == 0:
          return True
      if target_sum < 0:
          return False

      for num in numbers:
          if memoCanSum(target_sum - num, numbers, memo) == True:
              memo[target_sum] = True
              return True

      memo[target_sum] = False
      return False


  if __name__ == "__main__":
      print(canSum(7, [2, 5, 7])) # Output: True
      print(canSum(7, [2, 4])) # Output: False
      print(canSum(9, [2, 4])) # Output: False
```

Here, another function is created `memoCanSum(target_sum, numbers, memo)` and called it from `canSum(target_sum, numbers)`. Now every time `canSum` is called, it will work fine because in every call `memo` is set to empty.